# How to use a for loop to generate multiple custom maps in terraform?

Tags: terraform

```
 "${var.name}-4hr-backup" = {
        schedule = "@every 4h"
        template = {
          includeClusterResources = true
          includedNamespaces      = "${var.included_namespaces}"
          includedResources       = "${var.included_resource}"
          excludedNamespaces      = "${var.excluded_namespaces}"
          excludedResources       = "${var.excluded_resource}"
          storageLocation         = "aws"
          snapshotVolumes         = true
          ttl                     = "24h0m0s"
        }
      }
```

I have the above map that I want to customise and re-create based on the number of namespaces in my k8s cluster.

I was planning on iterating over a list of namespaces using a for loop to generate the right amount of maps.

For example, something like a list: namespace_4hr_backup = [a,b,c]
and then using a loop: for name in namespace_4hr_backup create:

```
 a-4hr-backup = {
        schedule = "@every 4h"
        template = {
          includeClusterResources = true
          includedNamespaces      = "a"
          includedResources       = "${var.included_resource}"
          excludedNamespaces      = "${var.excluded_namespaces}"
          excludedResources       = "${var.excluded_resource}"
          storageLocation         = "aws"
          snapshotVolumes         = true
          ttl                     = "24h0m0s"
        }
      }

 b-4hr-backup = {
        schedule = "@every 4h"
        template = {
          includeClusterResources = true
          includedNamespaces      = "b"
          includedResources       = "${var.included_resource}"
          excludedNamespaces      = "${var.excluded_namespaces}"
          excludedResources       = "${var.excluded_resource}"
          storageLocation         = "aws"
          snapshotVolumes         = true
          ttl                     = "24h0m0s"
        }
      }

 c-4hr-backup = {
        schedule = "@every 4h"
        template = {
          includeClusterResources = true
          includedNamespaces      = "c"
          includedResources       = "${var.included_resource}"
          excludedNamespaces      = "${var.excluded_namespaces}"
          excludedResources       = "${var.excluded_resource}"
          storageLocation         = "aws"
          snapshotVolumes         = true
          ttl                     = "24h0m0s"
        }
      }
```

What would be the best way to go about this - I had a look at the documentation and it wasn't very clear to me as I only saw basic examples.

Comment: Where is that first value coming from, a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create separate maps, but you can create a map of maps. For example:

```
locals {
  namespace_4hr_backup = ["a","b","c"]
  
  namespace_maps = {
      for name in local.namespace_4hr_backup:
          "${name}-4hr-backup" => {
                schedule = "@every 4h" 
                template = {
                  includeClusterResources = true
                  includedNamespaces      = "${name}"
                  includedResources       = "${var.included_resource}"
                  excludedNamespaces      = "${var.excluded_namespaces}"
                  excludedResources       = "${var.excluded_resource}"
                  storageLocation         = "aws"
                  snapshotVolumes         = true
                  ttl                     = "24h0m0s"
                }
             }    
        }   
}
```